# Android gallery photo - read bytes for upload

Tags: android, file, byte, gallery, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to let the user select an image via gallery. **My goal is to upload the selected images bytes to a webservice.** Unfortunately, I only manage to display the image in an ImageView, but not to read the bytes from the file.

Intent:

```
val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Constants.INTENT_ID_GALLERY)
```

On Result:

```
val imageUri: Uri? = data!!.data
```

Set Image to ImageView (works):

```
imageview1!!.setImageURI(imageUri)
```

Reading file bytes: (does not work)

```
val filePathColumn = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
val cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null)
cursor!!.moveToFirst()
val columnIndex = cursor!!.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0])
var picturePath = cursor!!.getString(columnIndex)
cursor!!.close()
val file = File(picturePath)
val bytes = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file)
```

In picturePath I get files like:

```
/storage/3234-3064/DCIM/Camera/file.jpg
/storage/3234-3064/DCIM/Screenshots/file.jpg
/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/file.jpg
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/file.jpg
/storage/emulated/0/Autodesk/SketchBook3/SketchBookPreview/file.jpg
```

Please anybody tell me how to properly **access the File and read its bytes**.

In crydle I added: *implementation "commons-io:commons-io:2.7"*

Comment: You've gotten access to the `Uri`, not to a File or path. Is there a reason you are not reading the bytes directly from the Uri via [`ContentResolver.openInputStream()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openInputStream(android.net.Uri))?

Comment: And, in particular, if you are uploading via OkHttp/Retrofit, there are `RequestBody` implementations designed specifically for this case. See https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html and https://cketti.de/2020/05/23/content-uris-and-okhttp/ for two.

Comment: Thx @ianhanniballake. Simply I didn't know about **ContentResolver.openInputStream()** function. Seems to work though

Answer (score 0):

I found a code snippet on java2s:

[Android ContentResolver Read readBytes(Uri uri, ContentResolver resolver)](http://www.java2s.com/example/android-utility-method/contentresolver-read/readbytes-uri-uri-contentresolver-resolver-86932.html)

Works just fine to get the bytes of the Uri, finally :-)